# jquery grabs the value null instead of correct one from the cell of dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to update my table row dynamically for which I should grab the value of table cell using jquery. The problem is that the grabbed value is null instead of "Title". Could you please check my code below and help me to find the mistake. I have researched and found out that I should use text() instead of html() but still could not get the result.

```
$.each(data.results, function(i, res) {                
                var row = $('<tr>').append(
                        $('<td>').html(res.id),
                        $('<td class="title" contenteditable="true">').html(res.title),
                        $('<td>').html('<a href="#" class="update" name="'+res.id+'">Update</a>')                                                               
                    );
                item.append(row); 
            });         
            $("#show").html(item);          
            $("body").on("click", ".update", function() {               
                var self = this;
                var id = $(self).attr("name");
                var title = $(self).closest(".title").text(); //cannot grab the value, 
                ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It should be

```
var title = $(self).closest('tr').children('td.title').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest` looks for the match in the parent elements , you should use `siblings` instead ...

UPDATE

one of these should work based on the code u provided, if they don't you need to provide the generated html or at least the complete code you using ...

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings('.title').text();
$(this).closest('tr').find('.title').text();
$(this).parent().prev().text();
... and some other methods
```

the reason why `$(this).siblings('.title').text()` doesn't work is because `this` is `<a>` not `<td>` witch doesn't have a sibling

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have just tried in the way you described but unfortunately it still does not work. I also tried **var title = $(self).parent().find(".title").text();**

Comment: @EducateYourself then there is something wrong with your html output

Comment: but the cell value can be displayed correctly, the problem is that I cannot grab that value